# Difference between fish feed and fish food

Tags: question-tags

I'm  asking  what is the difference between fish feed and fish food

Comment: Never heard of "fish feed", only "fish food". I have heard of "cattle feed" though...

Answer (score 1):

I think "fish feed" is only used in a commercial sense but "fish food" is more general, it can contain both commercial food and all the other foods that're appropriate for fish species.